How do we set examples for some API paths that do not return any response , the return just the status code
I have a PUT request, which on success returns a 201 response but no body or content. How can i make an example of such kind in any yaml file. Kindly provide example for better understanding.
I tried with:
body:
  type: null

but it did not work

Thanks Gagan for your question. CTO of Specmatic here. Can you please share some more details. Will be helpful if you can share a more complete snippet of your OpenAPI YAML. Also I am wondering if what you are reporting is related to this issue https://github.com/znsio/specmatic/issues/1063. If yes, it will be great if you can upvote the same on Github so we can prioritise the same.

Yes harikrishna, that was my issue. What am I understanding is that you are working on that enhancement.... I have another doubt if you can answer. I need a way so that , the yaml file that I am using as a contract I am making a post request which returns some response object. Can I use the actual value from that response to be used as the input for next request or text. Dp we support this. Basically what I am doing is a sort of cleanup. Like during test if I am creating something that I must be able to delete it within th test itself. If we support it plz provide an example or  documentation

Thanks Gagandeep for your response. OpenAPI Links (https://swagger.io/docs/specification/links/) should be able to help you use actual value from a response in a subsequent request. Support for the same is part of our Roadmap (https://specmatic.in/roadmap/) in Q2 2024.

Thanks for your response hari , so u mean currently I wont be able to do so? Until the next version or update comes

Hi harikrishnan, can u please look into this.  https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/78745763
